# How to add a capability to SELinux custom role?

Tags: linux, networking, selinux

I created a role `foo_r`, and I would like that a user with this role, can open a reserved port (< 1024) with the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability.
For this I added a security context:

```
policy_module(foo, 1.0)

role foo_r;

userdom_unpriv_user_template(foo)
allow foo_t self:capability net_bind_service;
```

I added `foo_r:foo_t` in `default_type` file and in `default_contexts` for `system_r:local_login_t` and `system_r:xdm_t` lines, as [explained here](https://selinuxproject.org/page/RefpolicyBasicRoleCreation).

My user can connect with this role, but when I want to open a reserved port with a python script, I get a “Permission Denied.”

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are managed Linux Capabilities with SELinux ? A former engineer from Red Hat told me :

> If this is a non root user, then the issue is you do not have the
> linux capability `NET_BIND_SERVICE`.  SELinux does not change the
> traditional Linux capabilities, it just adds further constraints.  So
> if you ran you `foo_t` as root you would be able to bind to this port.
> If you then removed the allow rule `foo_t` as root would not be allowed.

And a SELinux maintainer told me :

> Adding the capability is not enough, you'll also need something like
> `corenet_tcp_bind_all_reserved_ports(foo_t)` There are also permissions
> to bind and then accept the socket and to send traffic. SELinux will
> check all of them along the way

So for fix my problem : **firstly** i need to be root with my user, and **secondly** i must modify my file :

```
policy_module(foo, 1.0)

role foo_r;

userdom_unpriv_user_template(foo)
corenet_tcp_bind_all_reserved_ports(foo_t); # Line modified
```